# Convert a column in vaex dataframe from String to Float or int

Tags: vaex

I tried theis solution But it didn't really solve my problem

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
y = np.array(['10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60'])
z = np.array(['x', 'y', 'z', 'f', 'b', 's'])
df_vaex = vaex.from_arrays(x=x, y=y, z=z)

df_vaex.y = df_vaex.y.astype('float64')
print(df_vaex.dtypes)
```

#### output

```
x    <class 'str'>
y    <class 'str'>
z    <class 'str'>
dtype: object
```

how can I convert columns of string to numeric? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution  https://github.com/vaexio/vaex/issues/944

```
df_vaex['y'] = df_vaex.y.astype('float64')
```